# requestImageDataForAsset result handler improperly formatted

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, phasset

I am trying to request the full image from a PHAsset.

My code is as follows

```
@IBAction func nextTap(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        for asset in _selectedAssets
        {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: nil)
            {
                imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
                {
                    println("worked")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error though:

[image]

I have read the documentation on this call (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler:)

And I have, I think, followed the trailing syntax closure required, and put in the appropriate parameters.

I watched the WWDC 2014 video on this as well.

Cannot seem to get this to work for the full image.

If I want a smaller sized image, I used this code:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize:_cellSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil)
        {
            result, info in
            if reuseCount == cell.reuseCount
            {
                cell.imageView.image = result
                cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self._cellSize.width,self._cellSize.height)
            }
        }
```

And this works.

So Im not sure what I am doing wrong in my fist call but would love some insight in to how to request a full size image from a PHAsset and/or whats wrong with my syntax in the first code block.

Thanks

Update:
Here is the error message

"Cannot invoke 'println()' with an argument list type of '(PHAsset, options:NilLiteralConvertible, (($T6, ($T6,$T7,$T8,($T6,$T7,$T8)...."

Comment: Can you copy the error message into your question? It's small and difficult to read... it looks like it says "Cannot invoke 'println'", but that can't be right ... ...can it??

Comment: I updated with part of the error message. Its actually so long it gets cut off :/

Comment: I have seen issues on stackoverflow relating to long expressions in swift returning random incorrect results. These are resolved by breaking your expressions apart into smaller chunks. Have you tried assigning `PHImageManager.defaultManager()` to a variable with a short name and then calling `requestImageForAsset` on it? It's a longshot, but ... might work?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: It was the brackets!!!!!

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I wasn't reading the body of your closure where you were actually calling `println` and had assumed it was a crazy error that swift produced when it got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the brackets after the 'in' screw everything up.

Removing those brackets fixed the problem

```
for asset in _selectedAssets
        {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: nil)
            {
                imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
                println("worked")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(asset, options: requestOptions) {
    (imageData: NSData!, dataUTI: String!, orientation: UIImageOrientation, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    println("Yay!")
}
```